# grails wsdl2java script in Cxf Client plugin does not generate any java classes

Tags: java, web-services, grails, wsdl

I'm trying to run in grails the wsdl2java script in eclipse.

The console says :

> "Generating java stubs from WSDL_URL?WSDL Completed wsdl2java"

But in the end it shows TERMINATED and does not create any java classes.

I can't see what is wrong and where is the error.
I've tried it with other wsdl file and it worked fine.

My config.groovy file looks like this:

```
cxf {
client{
MessagingServiceSoapClient{
            wsdl = http://webapi.mymarketing.co.il/Messagi/MessagingService.asmx?WSDL
            //wsdlArgs = ['-autoNameResolution','-frontend','jaxws21']
            clientInterface = org.tempuri.MessagingServiceSoap
            serviceEndpointAddress = http://webapi.mymarketing.co.il/Messagi/MessagingService.asmx

        }
}
}
```

EDIT: I've found out the ERROR but not the solution to it:
    cxf ToolErrorListener - src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 's:schema'

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the [grails-cxf-client](https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-cxf-client) plugin.

I believe you are supposed to surround the `client` node with a `cxf` node as follows:

```
cxf {
    client {
        simpleServiceClient {
            //used in wsdl2java
            wsdl = "docs/SimpleService.wsdl" //only used for wsdl2java script target
            namespace = "cxf.client.demo.simple"
            client = false //defaults to false
            bindingFile = "grails-app/conf/bindings.xml"
            outputDir = "src/java"
            allowChunking = true //false

            //used for invoking service
            clientInterface = cxf.client.demo.simple.SimpleServicePortType
            serviceEndpointAddress = "${service.simple.url}"
        }

        //Another example real service to use against wsd2java script
        stockQuoteClient {
            wsdl = "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL"

            clientInterface = net.webservicex.StockQuoteSoap
            serviceEndpointAddress = "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've done that in my code and i'm using grails-cxf-client. It doesnt work. with other wsdl files i succeed to import and generate java files. I do not understand what is the problem with this wsdl file. I do not see any error.